# LinkButton in DataGrid, to trigger Multiple UpdatePanels

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a datagrid which lists products and their market share - (dgProd).  That datagrid is in a DIV to provide scrolling.

Clicking on one of the product names shows two more div/datagrid combinations - one with a summary (dgSummary) and one with with the detail records (dgDetail).

The postback of the dgProd provides the information for dgSummary and dgDetail to know what product to show.  But the postback loses the location in dgProd.

I've tried putting dgSummary and dgDetail into UpdatePanels but I'm still getting the full postback.  I considered changing the product name LinkButton to run some javascript instead of the traditional postback, but then I don't see how the server will get the appropriate product to show in the other 2 grids.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with jQuery.

Create a new ASP Page that contains your product detail and Product Summary

In the new ASp Page, Load the Summary Grid into a Div with id="Summary", Load the Detail into a Div with id="Detail"

Then, call your new Page with a jQuery.ajax(); call..

You can then load each of the "content" divs into placeholder divs in your main page using the #Summary, or #Detail method...

[This](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) is a good article to get you started and does demonstrate partial loading of remote content..

HTH.
Dave

Comment: I voted both of these up because each had an element of what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register each and every LinkButton as an AsyncPostBackTrigger within the UpdatePanel. After each item is bound in your DataGrid, you'll need to search for the LinkButton and register it through code as follows:

```
private void OnItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
       LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("myLinkButton");  
       ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
   }
}
```

Comment: I voted both of these up because each had an element of what I ended up doing.